# Have you ever seen Razor used without MVC in a JavaScript SPA?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I recently took over an application which combines a number of cshtml files written in Razor with a JavaScript spa. I've never seen this structure before and am wondering if anyone has run into this before?

```
/api
    /App_Code
        MyCache.cs - caches some data from an external API
        Application.cs - looks like the code behind for Global.asax
    Api.cshmtl - Uses razor syntax but the entire file is C# and it gets an auth Token and adds it to all api calls.
    Global.asax - without global.asax.cs
    web.config - not much helpful in here.
index.cshtml
```

Most of the .cshtml files use Razor syntax. Some are just calling a method from the MyCache.cs via  `@Html.Raw(myMethodFromCache)`.

Unfortunately, I don't have a .csproj or .sln file, so it's really hard to guess how this gets compiled. Also no package.config, so I don't know what version of the assemblies, but it only includes:

- System.Web.Helpers
- System.Web
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
- System.Web.WebPages
- System.WebPage.Razor

Have any of you see something like this before? Do you know if this is some older way of handling Spas with .NET?

Any suggestions you have are appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what this is. It is using ASP.NET Web Pages which is a package available on NuGet. It is a trimmed down version of ASP.NET with the Razor syntax and .cshtml pages without all of the overhead of MVC.

And it was set up to run as a "web site" instead of "web application" which means the application is built at runtime.